# Removing images deleted from uploads folder, from Media Library

Tags: attachments, media-library

How can I remove images that have been deleted from the upload folder, from the Media Library?

Comment: How did you delete them? Physically from the storage or?

Comment: @MaxYudin Yes, phisically deleted from the uploads folder

Comment: You have to edit the database now.

Comment: Is there no way to do this programtically? I can still delete the images in bulk from media library without touching the DB, but I'd like a different solution.

Comment: Did you delete the original images and all the custom image sizes aswell?

Comment: Yes. Parse posts having images, extract all images' URLs from the content, compare with the list of existing images, spy out deleted and replace those `<img />` tags with something or simply delete.

Comment: @MaxYudin I don't need to have them removed from posts, just from the Media Library.

Comment: Imagine, Media Librrrary gets the information from the database. Almost everything what happens in WordPress is tied to database. When you move files physically you do not move them inside database entries. So, see the solution written above.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete Images from Admin panel **Media** Tab manually using **Multi-select Deletion** option
OR 
Delete from DB also as per media attachment ids.
I think Multi select deletion from **Media** tab is the best way to delete.
Hope this will help you!